# SVN commit log marking files as Added that already exist in repo

Tags: svn

I keep seeing lines in SVN commit notification emails like:

> A \myproject\src\codefile123.cpp

When this file already exists in the repository. I can't tell if it's a little bug in the host (Codesion) or in SVN, or if something strange is going on.

We're using TortoiseSVN against SVN 1.6, if it has any relevance.

edit: If anyone else has seen this please comment, so I can gauge if it's a common problem or not.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try an `svn log -v` on the file in question to see the whole history?

Answer (score 1):

Certainly try looking at the log on that file (suggested already) to try to make sense why the file is added at that point (instead of just "U" updated).

However, if you think there is a bug, please open a support case with Codesion, and we'd love to take a closer look.

Answer (score 0):

Any chance these are actually file moves/copies? Subversion moves a file by deleting the original, and adding the new file/file at the new location with history, and copies by adding the file with history.